# Toggle HTML video visiblity on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video

I am creating a simple web app. There is a `<video>` element on the page. There is a login form that when opened overlays the entire screen, but if you are on the page with the video regardless of `z-index` or `visibility: hidden;` the video controls are on top of the overlay.

Well... They are below visually, but the hit areas are above, so you can't interact with the 
login form.

I have managed to solve this using `display: none;` on the `<video>` tag when the form opens (this is also what I tried with `visibility: hidden;` which didn't work) but it is not ideal as the page underneath shifts about quite a bit.

Has anyone had this issue and found a good way around it?

Thanks :)

---

*As I was typing this, I figured it out. I imagine it's an issue other people will have, so I've answered it below. Nice and simple!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide the controls using a bit of javascript/jQuery:

```
$('video').prop('controls',false);
```

Works a treat.